# What is the limit to output numbers in C?

Tags: c, output

I was practicing programming in C, and when I ran this code, it came to a point where the outputting numbers just gave up lol, it was around the 30th number of the sequence.
What is the limit to output numbers in C?
(I was trying the Fibonacci sequence)

```
int main() {
    
    int fibo, i, n, a, aux;
    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &fibo);
    
    n = 1; a = 1;
    
    printf("1 1 ");
    
    for(i = 3; i <= fibo; i++){
       /* aux = n;
        n = n + a;
        a = aux;*/
        
        n += a;
        a = n - a;
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: The largest `int` a program can deal with is `INT_MAX` (remember to `#include <limits.h>` if you want to use that value directly) ... `printf("ints go from %d to %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);`

Comment: What do you mean by "gave up"? Please describe the problem properly

Comment: You can use `unsigned long long fibo, i, n, a, aux;` to increase the range.

Comment: This is usually mentioned in the first chapters of most C programming books. Otherwise, what happens if you type "c integer limits" at www.google.com?

Comment: As others have said, we need a tad more clarity, here.  Maybe a line-buffering issue; what happens if you change your output to put in a newline: `printf("%d\n", n);`?

Comment: The 30th number in the F. sequence is only 514229 (starting with 0 1 1 2 3 5...) Maybe try printing a counter alongside the number to track how far you actually are getting...

Comment: Is your terminal software printing just one line and stopping at the end rather than going on to a new line when a lot of text is printed on a single line? If you change `printf("%d ", n);` to `printf("%d\n", n);`, do you see more output, on separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the limit to output numbers in C?

There is no such limit. You can create a library to do arithmetic operations on arbitrary large numbers - and output them.

The question should probably be "what ranges can the fundamental types in C represent?" - and there are different limits for the different fundamental types.

Here's an incomplete list of some types taken from [`limits.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits):

- `INT_MIN` - minimum value of `int`
- `INT_MAX` - maximum value of `int`
- `LLONG_MIN` - minimum value of `long long int`
- `LLONG_MAX` - maximum value of `long long int`

And from `float.h`:

- `DBL_MIN` - minimum, normalized, positive value of `double` (typically `0.`)
- `-DBL_MAX` - lowest finite value representable by `double`
- `DBL_MAX` - maximum finite value of `duuble`

Note that

- an `int` is required to be at least 16 bit wide, but is often 32.
- a `long int` is required to be at least 32 bit wide and often is.
- a `long long int` is required to be at least 64 bites wide.

Depending on the type's bit width and how the implementation make use of these bits (two's complement, ones' complement, sign–magnitude and for floating points, if they use IEEE 754 or something else) affects the ranges they can represent.

Answer (score -1):

Fibonacci numbers get very large very quickly, and will exceed the range of native integer types for relatively small `n`.  On my system, the largest Fibonacci number I can compute with the following code using a regular signed `int` is F(44):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  if ( argc < 2 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s n\n", argv[0] );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  int n = strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10 );
  int f[3] = { 0, 1, 0 };

  printf( "INT_MAX = %d\n", INT_MAX );

  for ( int i = 1; i <= n && INT_MAX - f[2] > f[1] + f[0]; i++ )
  {
    f[2] = f[1] + f[0];
    f[0] = f[1];
    f[1] = f[2];
    printf( "fib %3d = %10d\n", i, f[2] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./fib 50
INT_MAX = 2147483647
fib   1 =          1
fib   2 =          2
fib   3 =          3
fib   4 =          5
fib   5 =          8
fib   6 =         13
fib   7 =         21
fib   8 =         34
fib   9 =         55
fib  10 =         89
fib  11 =        144
fib  12 =        233
fib  13 =        377
fib  14 =        610
fib  15 =        987
fib  16 =       1597
fib  17 =       2584
fib  18 =       4181
fib  19 =       6765
fib  20 =      10946
fib  21 =      17711
fib  22 =      28657
fib  23 =      46368
fib  24 =      75025
fib  25 =     121393
fib  26 =     196418
fib  27 =     317811
fib  28 =     514229
fib  29 =     832040
fib  30 =    1346269
fib  31 =    2178309
fib  32 =    3524578
fib  33 =    5702887
fib  34 =    9227465
fib  35 =   14930352
fib  36 =   24157817
fib  37 =   39088169
fib  38 =   63245986
fib  39 =  102334155
fib  40 =  165580141
fib  41 =  267914296
fib  42 =  433494437
fib  43 =  701408733
fib  44 = 1134903170
```

If I switch to `unsigned int`, I can compute up to F(45).  If I use `long`, I can get up to F(90).  But even if I use `unsigned long long`, I'll still exceed its range with relatively small `n`.

To compute Fibonacci sequences for arbitrarily large `n`, you'll need a third-party bignum library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  if ( argc < 2 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s n\n", argv[0] );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  int n = strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10 );
  mpz_t f[3];

  mpz_init_set_str( f[0], "1", 10 );
  mpz_init_set_str( f[1], "1", 10 );

  for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
  {
    mpz_add( f[2], f[1], f[0] );
    mpz_set( f[0], f[1] );
    mpz_set( f[1], f[2] );
    gmp_printf( "fib %d = %Zd\n", i, f[2] );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

For `n == 1000`, I get

```
fib 1000 = 113796925398360272257523782552224175572745930353730513145086634176691092536145985470146129334641866902783673042322088625863396052888690096969577173696370562180400527049497109023054114771394568040040412172632376
```

**Edit**

Gah, the sequence starts off wrong - it should be `1, 1, 2, ...`.  But my main point remains.